# get error while installing gcc with yum

Tags: centos, yum, gcc, dependencies

i changed my yum repository to `/media` and mounted iso of `CentOS-7-x86` to `/media` and used `yum install packagename` to install packages with dependencies, got no errors but when i tried to install `gcc` i got this error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (c7-media)
       Requires: glibc = 2.17-260.el7
       Installed: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.5.i686 (@updates)
           glibc = 2.17-260.el7_6.5
       Available: glibc-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (c7-media)
           glibc = 2.17-260.el7
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (c7-media)
       Requires: glibc = 2.17-260.el7
       Installed: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.5.i686 (@updates)
           glibc = 2.17-260.el7_6.5
       Available: glibc-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (c7-media)
           glibc = 2.17-260.el7
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i don't know how to solve this or why i get error.
the version of OS is: `centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64`
what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

You have packages from the 'updates' repository installed, which are newer than what's on the ISO media, which only has packages from the original date of that point release.  Yum can't get the dependencies (since it appears you've turned off updates), because the updated glibc package requires you install glibc-headers of the same release, which is not available.